# How to convert java object correctly for jsonPath matcher?

Tags: java, json, spring, mockmvc

I'm writing mockMvc tests for my controller, and need to validate jsonPath return value.

Have tried differently with .is() and .value(), mapping, in any way i can imagine with no success

```
Loan loan = new Loan(
                "0000-0000",
                "OPEN",
                LocalDate.now(),
                LocalDate.now().plusDays(30),
                new BigDecimal("500.0"),
                new BigDecimal("50.0"),
                new BigDecimal("550.0"),
                new ArrayList<>()
        );

    Mockito.lenient()
            .when(loanService.loans())
            .thenReturn(Collections.singletonList(loan));

    String json = MAPPER.writeValueAsString(loan);

    mockMvc.perform(get("/api/loans"))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.*").value(json));



Expected :{"id":"0000-0000","status":"OPEN","created":"2019-05-09","dueDate":"2019-06-08","principal":500.0,"interest":50.0,"total":550.0,"extensions":[]}
Actual   :{id=0000-0000, status=OPEN, created=2019-05-09, dueDate=2019-06-08, principal=500.0, interest=50.0, total=550.0, extensions=[]}
```

So this is the closes i got, just dont get the types here.

Comment: How does the response look when you hit the endpoint on postman?

Comment: postman response [
    {
        "id": "8706-2150",
        "status": "OPEN",
        "created": "2019-05-09",
        "dueDate": "2019-06-08",
        "principal": 400,
        "interest": 40,
        "total": 440,
        "extensions": []
    }
]

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to assert the complete responseBody as a json, you may use `MockMvcResultMatchers`'s `content` method.

Just replace `jsonPath("$.*").value(json)` with `content().json(json)` as below

```
mockMvc.perform(get("/api/loans"))
            .andExpect(content().json(json));
```